# Calculating the derivative of a fully connected layer using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, derivative

I'm implementing my own neural network from scratch (educational purposes, I know there are faster and better libraries for this) and for that I'm trying to calculate the derivative of a fully connected layer. I know the following:

[image]

and assuming I have a way to calculate the derivative of f using `f.derivative(<some_matrix>)`, how can I use numpy to efficiently calculate the derivative of `f(XW)` with respect to `W` as seen in the picture?

I want to be able to calculate the derivative for `N` different inputs at the same time (giving me a 4-d tensor, 1 dimension for the `N` samples, and 3 dimensions for the derivative in the image).

**Note**: `f.derivative` takes in a matrix of `N` inputs with `d` features each, and returns the derivative of each of the input points.